# How do you convert Stopwatch ticks to nanoseconds, milliseconds and seconds?

Tags: c#

This is a very basic question...quite embarassing, but here goes:

I have a Stopwatch block in C# code.  I determine the elapsed time in ticks and then want to convert to ns, ms, s.  I know that the Frequency is provided by the Stopwatch class and that it is required for conversion.

Thanks

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Stopwatch.Elapsed is a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan_members%28VS.71%29.aspx), so you can do `myStopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds`, `myStopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds`, etc.

```
// Create new stopwatch
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

// Begin timing
stopwatch.Start();

// Do something
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1);
}

// Stop timing
stopwatch.Stop();

// Write result
Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed (s): {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed (ms): {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed (ns): {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds * 1000000);
```

**Output:**

```
Time elapsed (s): 2.4976622
Time elapsed (ms): 2497.6622
Time elapsed (ns): 2497662200
```

**Note** that `stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds` returns a `long` and is thus only precise up to the millisecond, while `stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds` returns a `double` and **has the same precision** as `stopwatch.ElapsedTicks`, except it's easier to use. ILSpy shows that `TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds` is computed using ticks anyway.

Comment: That's very inaccurate, though, since it's going to provide NS rounded to the nearest MS.

Comment: No it isn't, milliseconds is a double (see the output I added).

Comment: While this does convert the number of milliseconds to nanoseconds, it doesn't improve the precision of the result.

Under the covers, Stopwatch uses native calls that provide far better precision than milliseconds.  The "milliseconds" limitation was for backward compatibility.  (Older OS's lack the High Performance Counter).

I recommend an approach that uses ticks divided by Stopwatch.Frequency.  Other people have posted answers to this effect.

See the answers from Reed Copsey or Zach Johnson for examples.

Answer (score 84):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.frequency.aspx), Frequency tells you the number of ticks per second.  Therefore:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
// ...
double ticks = sw.ElapsedTicks;
double seconds = ticks / Stopwatch.Frequency;
double milliseconds = (ticks / Stopwatch.Frequency) * 1000;
double nanoseconds = (ticks / Stopwatch.Frequency) * 1000000000;
```

Comment: 1) `sw.ElapsedTicks` returns `long` 2) cast ticks to `double` or `decimal` before divided by `Frequency`

Comment: @GlennSlayden in the edit summary of your [latest edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2329103/7) I can see this: *"it's got other problems though, which I'll add to the comments section."* Would you like to elaborate? I am interested to know what the problems are, because I intend to use this code.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Embarassed to say that I can't recall. Perhaps it was related to what the other commenter mentioned in the first comment, which was 9 months after my edit.

Answer (score 30):

[Stopwatch.Frequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.frequency.aspx) gives you ticks/second.

So, if you have ticks, you can just divide by frequency to get seconds:

```
long ticks = sw.ElapsedTicks;
double ns = 1000000000.0 * (double)ticks / Stopwatch.Frequency;
double ms = ns / 1000000.0;
double s = ms / 1000;
```

For example, you can do:

```
static void Main()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3456);
    sw.Stop();

    long ticks = sw.ElapsedTicks;
    double ns = 1000000000.0 * (double)ticks / Stopwatch.Frequency;
    double ms = ns / 1000000.0;
    double s = ms / 1000;

    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", ns, ms, s);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Which, on my system, prints:

```
3455650175.58075, 3455.65017558075, 3.45565017558075
```

Comment: So 1ns corresponds to 1000000000s. That doesn't seem right. :)

Answer (score 11):

Use this class:

```
public static class Utility
{
    public static long ElapsedNanoSeconds(this Stopwatch watch)
    {
         return watch.ElapsedTicks * 1000000000 / Stopwatch.Frequency;
    }
    public static long ElapsedMicroSeconds(this Stopwatch watch)
    {
        return watch.ElapsedTicks * 1000000 / Stopwatch.Frequency;
    }
}
```

Then you can get the elapsed nanoseconds/microseconds just like this:

```
var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
//... measured code part
Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedNanoSeconds());
// OR
Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMicroSeconds());
```

For milliseconds you can use the ElapsedMilliseconds() method of Stopwatch.

Comment: Watch for an overflow! Might be better to divide ElapsedTicks by the Frequency (casting to double) and then multiplying by the constant.

Answer (score 5):

From the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx):

Use the [Frequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.frequency.aspx) and [IsHighResolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.ishighresolution.aspx) fields to determine the precision and resolution of the Stopwatch timing implementation.

```
long frequency = Stopwatch.Frequency;
Console.WriteLine("  Timer frequency in ticks per second = {0}",
    frequency);
long nanosecPerTick = (1000L*1000L*1000L) / frequency;
Console.WriteLine("  Timer is accurate within {0} nanoseconds", 
    nanosecPerTick);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Elapsed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed.aspx) property:

```
stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds
```