# Returning Tenths and Hundredth of a Second from a Stopwatch

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, stopwatch

So I'm getting closer and closer to making the timer work the way I want it to, with one small problem.

I found the following post about returning millisecond and nanosecond:
[How do you convert Stopwatch ticks to nanoseconds, milliseconds and seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329079/how-do-you-convert-stopwatch-ticks-to-nanoseconds-milliseconds-and-seconds)

But what I'm trying to do is show only the 10ths of 100ths of a second when desired.

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub TotalTimer_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TotalTimer.Tick
    Dim elapsed As TimeSpan = Me.matchStopwatch.Elapsed

    Me.MatchClockLbl.Text = String.Format("{0:0}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:###}", _
                                   Math.Floor(elapsed.TotalHours), _
                                   elapsed.Minutes, _
                                   elapsed.Seconds, _
                                   (elapsed.Milliseconds / 100))

End Sub
```

Now I tried to change the part of code from {3:000} to {3:0} or {3:00} but all this does is change format, it doesn't actually remove the 1000ths digit or 1000ths digit, they still show up.

I further found this on the MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx#fSpecifier

But I keep getting s.f or s/f or something that's not right.

**EDIT:** Added in the modified version of the code, thanks Oded. The new problem now is that the label likes to flicker the extra digits once in a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide `Milliseconds` by 10 to get 100th of a second and by 100 to get 10th of a second.

This works by integer division - essentially throwing away the least significant digits and assumes `Milliseconds` returns at most 3 digits.

Comment: One small problem. As I'm doing this, I notice that when it comes to one full second, the display flicks out the full 3 zeroes. Like I would see 0.9 then 0.000 then 0.1 again.

Comment: @Paul - change the format specifier from `{3:000}` to `{3}`, or `{3:##}`.

Comment: Getting closer. Now it flicks out one additional digit.

Comment: @Paul - It looks like your options are then `{3:0}` or `{3:#}`.

Comment: Well the problem now is that on either one, the label is showing: 0:00:00.10 when I'm trying to show tenths or 0:00:00.100 when I'm showing hundredths. It's getting there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7244/discussion-between-paul-williams-and-oded)

Comment: Okay I eventually fixed this by using Math.Floor(elapsed.Milliseconds / 100). This clears the extra digit for good and still reports accurately. Thanks all.