# Why is my tail call-optimized implementation faster than the normal recursive if it's not supported in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, benchmarking, compiler-optimization, tail-call-optimization

I recently got introduced to the concept of tail-call optimization and as far as I can read it's not inherently supported in the .NET compiler but there is a workaround called "Trampolining" which I've not made use of yet.

How can it be my "SumRecTail" benchmarks as slightly faster than my "SumRec" function if it's not supported? Given I don't have an error in my benchmarking...

```
   public class Program
   {
    private static readonly int n = 100;
    private static readonly int[] a = Enumerable.Range(0, n).ToArray();


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mark("Marking regular recursion", SumRec);
        Mark("Marking tail recursion", SumRecTail);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static double Mark(string description, Func<int, double> method)
    {
        int noOfRuns = 30;
        int count = 100_000;
        double st = 0.0, sst = 0.0, dummy = 0.0;
        Console.WriteLine(description);
        for (int j = 0; j < noOfRuns; j++)
        {
            Timer t = new Timer();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                dummy += method(n);
            }
            double time = t.CheckNanoSeconds() / count;
            st += time;
            sst += time * time;
        }
        double mean = st / noOfRuns, sdev = Math.Sqrt((sst - mean * mean * noOfRuns) / (noOfRuns - 1));
        Console.WriteLine("avg {0} ns, {1} sdev", Math.Round(mean, 5), Math.Round(sdev, 5));
        return dummy / noOfRuns;
    }

    public static double Mark(string description, Func<int, int, double> method)
    {
        int noOfRuns = 30;
        int count = 100_000;
        double st = 0.0, sst = 0.0, dummy = 0.0;
        Console.WriteLine(description);
        for (int j = 0; j < noOfRuns; j++)
        {
            Timer t = new Timer();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                dummy += method(n, 0);
            }
            double time = t.CheckNanoSeconds() / count;
            st += time;
            sst += time * time;
        }
        double mean = st / noOfRuns, sdev = Math.Sqrt((sst - mean * mean * noOfRuns) / (noOfRuns - 1));
        Console.WriteLine("avg {0} ns, {1} sdev", Math.Round(mean, 5), Math.Round(sdev, 5));
        return dummy / noOfRuns;
    }

    private static double SumRecTail(int start, int sum)
    {
        return start == 0 ? sum : SumRecTail(start - 1, sum + start);
    }

    private static double SumRec(int end)
    {
        return end > 0 ? SumRec(end - 1) + end : 0;
    }
}
```

The timer class:

```
   public class Timer
{
    private readonly Stopwatch StopWatch = null;

    public Timer()
    {
        StopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    }

    public double CheckNanoSeconds()
    {
        return StopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds * 1000000;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Marking regular recursion
avg 2044,21167 ns, 621,95915 sdev

Marking tail recursion
avg 1857,5378 ns, 69,5234 sdev
```

Comment: It *is* supported. Support was added in the .NET 4.0 x64 runtime

Comment: For accurate benchmarking, I suggest you use https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet, it does a lot to ensure what you intend to measure is what you're *actually* measuring.  It can also provide disassembly diagnostics.  Quite useful.

Comment: Support for tail recursion means that if you get the guard condition wrong you won't get an exception any more. Execution will continue until the process is manually killed, pegging the CPU at 100%. Guess how I know ....

Comment: Is it possible that passing two instead of one argument to a function can be the reason?

Comment: That explains it then @PanagiotisKanavos. Google hit me up with outdated answers then. I should have been more concise in my research

Comment: The IL supports a tailcall instruction that C# never generates; however, the jitter is still allowed to generate a tailcall if it decides that it can do so safely.

Comment: @RufusL according to this post it does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329079/how-do-you-convert-stopwatch-ticks-to-nanoseconds-milliseconds-and-seconds

Comment: @J.Kirk. Oh, I stand corrected! I thought it was 1000 milliseconds. :(